# What is the point of paper alchemical cartridges?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, firearms

Using a paper cartridge cost 1 gold more than just a bullet and a dose of black powder, so what exactly is the point of having them when you can just have a bullet and some loose black powder?

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! I assume the downvotes are for lack of research. People like to assume that if something is easy for them to find, it must be for everyone else as well.

Comment: That's certainly why I downvoted: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 11):

Paper alchemical cartridges [reload faster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/firearms#TOC-Firearm-Ammunition-and-Adventuring-Gear) than a standard bullet.  They reload one step faster than a regular bullet.